# Rails - Mysql2::Error: MySQL client is not connected: ROLLBACK

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem with my rails app, when trying to create an object that has a data column of type LONGTEXT in which I store JSON string. The problem happens only when I'm trying to create/update an object with quite a big data value (4M characters). The error I receive is:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Mysql2::Error:  MySQL client is not connected: ROLLBACK
```

At first, I thought that I'm trying to store more data than Mysql supports, however, it seems that is not the problem.
Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

**EDIT**:
this is adapter configuration:

```
  adapter: mysql2
  username: [username]
  password: [password]
  host: [host]
  port: [port]
  reaping_frequency: 0 # could this line cause the problem?
```

**UPDATE**:
The solution I found after playing with multiple variables and searching for other posts with similar problems is changing the servers `max_allowed_packet` to a higher value since reading the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html) and some recommendations in the comments it seemed as the most likely culprit. However, we still experience this problem in some environments even after changing it so there might be a few other variables influencing this.

Comment: Interesting. What if you take a smaller part of your string (let's say 1/10th, maybe do huge_str[0..400000])

Comment: does this error only happen on development environment ? try disable log

Comment: The error occurred first in production. @LamPhan

Comment: I was able to reproduce it with a fake data string of length 30M (with a much smaller initial table). It worked with a string with 1M characters. @Joel_Blum

Comment: @sava128 try to increase `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` or `max_allowed_packet`

Comment: the thing is I can't just change those variables in production, and locally I have different variables but I have a feeling that has something to do with MySQL since I've seen those errors in production even with smaller data. @LamPhan

Comment: @sava128 how about auto-reconnect: https://dalibornasevic.com/posts/77-auto-reconnect-for-activerecord-connections (change `if e.message =~ /server has gone away/i` to `if e.message =~ /client is not connected/i`)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work, I also noticed this error with other models with much smaller objects, This makes me wonder if perhaps it has something to do with adapter configuration

Comment: also I've add the config of the adapter, could the last line cause the problem? @LamPhan

Comment: @sava128 maybe this is an issue of `mysql2` gem, take a look: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/947, still open.

Comment: @sava128, you can try the configuration this blog suggest: https://engineering.grab.com/deep-dive-into-database-timeouts-in-rails, `reconnect: false, reaping_frequency: 120, connect_timeout: 5, read_timeout: 5`

Comment: @LamPhan sorry for the late reply, I kinda dropped this issue for a while, but It became more urgent so changing the max allowed packet seemed to do the trick for some cases. Thank you!